# permission error when populating a table in PostGreSQL copying from a csv file

Tags: postgresql, permissions, privileges, pgadmin

I know this issue has already been raised by others, but even trying previous suggestions I still get this error...

When I try to populate a table copying from a csv file, I get a permission error.

```
COPY Eurasia FROM '/Users/Oritteropus/Desktop/eurasia1.csv' CSV HEADER;

ERROR: could not open file "/Users/Oritteropus/Desktop/eurasia1.csv" for reading: Permission denied
SQL state: 42501
```

As previously suggested in these cases, I changed the permission of the file (chmod 711 eurasia1.csv or chmod a+r eurasia1.csv) and I also changed the user rights with:

```
ALTER USER postgres WITH SUPERUSER; #where postgres is my user
```

However, I still get the same error. 
I also tried to manually change the privileges from pgAdmin but seems avery privilege is already given. 
I'm working on a Mac Os and I'm using PostGreSQL 9.2.4.

Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: check user and group to which this file belongs

Comment: The file belongs to Oritteropus user (the computer user): -rwxr-xr-x@ 1 Oritteropus  staff  390018694 25 Mag 05:54 eurasia1.csv

Comment: The file will be read by the account under which the Postgres server runs. Check if that account has the necessary permissions, including on all directories in the path.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, I checked in System preferences the 'users & groups' and I set PostGreSQL as admin, I restarted the computer but nothing changed. Is it what you intended? What you mean for "directories in the path"?

Comment: Ok I solved, I had to give permission to the postgres user to every single folder in the path.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to change and use `COPY FROM STDIN` as that avoids quite a number of permissions issues.

Alternatively you can make sure that the postgres user can access the file.  This rarely better than `COPY FROM STDIN` however for a couple reasons.

1. `COPY TO STDOUT` can conceivably corrupt your data.  Because this involves file I/O by PostgreSQL if bugs exist in `COPY FROM STDIN` that could be a problem too.
2. If you are doing it on the server side because of automation/stored proc concerns, this is rarely a win, as you are combining transactional and non-transactional effects.  COPY TO STDOUT and COPY FROM STDIN do not have these issues.  (For example, you don't have to wonder whether the atime of the inode actually means the file was properly processed).